# Kohana 3.3 ORM - how to find all ancestors in a tree (self-referencing table)

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3, self-referencing-table

How to find all the ancestors (not only direct parent) of a record with the following model:

```
class Model_Category extends ORM {

protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'parent' => array('model' => 'Category', 'foreign_key' => 'category_id'),
);

protected $_has_many = array(
        'children' => array('model' => 'Category', 'foreign_key' => 'category_id'),
);
```

$category->parent->find() is only giving the direct parent and even when trying to fetch the parent of the parent with a recursive function it throws Kohana_Exception: Method find() cannot be called on loaded objects.

This occurs so natural to me that I guess there must an easy way to do it - I'm not sure if it's me or the lack of documentation on ORM relations - halp!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a recursive function or a while loop

```
$current = $category;
while ($current->parent->loaded())
{
    //save $current
    $current = $category->parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). For example, https://github.com/evopix/orm-mptt. It has special methods like `parents()`, `children()`, `siblings()` etc. Of course, this requires modifications in your DB table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the related models actually ARE included, cause if you do

$category->parent->parent->name it will be the name of the grand-parent of $category.

My problem was that I was printing $category->parent->as_array() and expecting to see the parent relations in the (multidimensional) array which simply appears not to be the case with kohana.